# Compatible LITE version and Incompatible PRO

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

I published 2 version of my app: some user do see the LITE version and don't see the PRO one.
Both build are identical except for:

the pro has this two more feature

```
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission:'com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE'
```

this is the result using aapt tool:

**LITE VERSION:**

```
package: name='it.android.smartscreenonlite' versionCode='3' versionName='1.2'
sdkVersion:'3'
targetSdkVersion:'15'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.sensor.proximity'
application-label:'Smart Screen ON LITE'
application-label-fr:'Smart Screen ON LITE'
application-label-es:'Encendido Inteligente LITE'
application-label-it:'Accendi Schermo Intelligente LITE'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application: label='Smart Screen ON LITE' icon='res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
launchable-activity: name='it.android.smartscreenonlite.ActivityImpostazioni'  l
abel='Smart Screen ON LITE' icon='res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'fr' 'es' 'it'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

**PRO VERSION:**

```
package: name='it.android.smartscreenon' versionCode='3' versionName='1.2'
sdkVersion:'3'
targetSdkVersion:'15'
uses-permission:'com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-permission:'android.permission.USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.sensor.proximity'
application-label:'Smart Screen ON'
application-label-fr:'Smart Screen ON'
application-label-es:'Encendido Inteligente'
application-label-it:'Accendi Schermo Intelligente'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
application: label='Smart Screen ON' icon='res/drawable-hdpi/smartscreenon.png'
launchable-activity: name='it.android.smartscreenon.LicenseCheck'  label='Smart
Screen ON' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'fr' 'es' 'it'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Those users are already using other app which uses the same permissions (license and boot one). What's the problem?